# Get File Bytes from Resource file in C#

Tags: c#, resources, byte

I used to store the resources in the actual project, but I've switched to using a resource file instead.  Originally I could ready the bytes for a file, but I'm finding it difficult doing this with a resource file.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public static byte[] ReadResource(string resourceName)
{
    using (Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int read = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    return ms.ToArray();
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The files I want to read our added as links and in a folder in the project called Resources.  Using this function keep causing an object reference error

Comment: Then load the assembly with the resources instead of the current execution context.

Answer (score 2):

Or add this in your resource class

```
internal static byte[] GetResource(string fileName) { 
    object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject(fileName, resourceCulture); 
    return ((byte[])(obj)); 
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work, at least it won't work when obj is a BitMap.