# Copy csv Resource file to hard disk

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a Problem while trying to copy a file, that I would like to use as a database from resources to the documents folder in the current windows user direction.(file = Vorlage.csv)

I was trying to do this since four hours now and I used every explanation I found in the internet but I always get an error. Maybe it's just because I don't have the knowledge for that yet.

So what I did with the instructions in the internet is the following Code:

```
private void firststart()
{   
     ///Beim Ersten Start ausgeführt:
     string direction = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

     if (!(Directory.Exists(direction + "\\MKD-Manager")))
     {
         ///Progrmmordner erstellen
         Directory.CreateDirectory(direction + "\\MKD-Manager");
         ///Vorlage für die Datenbank Auf den Pc kopieren
         File.WriteAllBytes(direction + "\\MKD-Manager\\Vorlage.doc", MyProgramm.Properties.Resources.Vorlage.csv);
     }
}
```

When I do it like this, I don't find the "Vorlage.csv" file in the

MyProgramm.Properties.Ressources

It's just not there.

While trying solutions, I saw that there was a MyProgramm.Ressource1.Vorlage.csv File.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(direction + "\\MKD-Manager\\Vorlage.doc", MassageKundenDatenbank.Resource1.Vorlage);
```

When I try the same thing with this one I get an error that says, that it couldn't have been converted in byte type.

So because I don't understand that errors I'm asking you now. I'm sorry if this is just too easy but I just don't get it. And it's important for my application to have this file local in this folder.

Comment: Please copy and the whole error/exception into your question.

Comment: This is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709373/get-file-bytes-from-resource-file-in-c-sharp. Also notice, you getting `Vorlage.CSV` and writing `Vorlage.DOC`. Also, you have to move file writing outside the `if` where you create directory

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only doing write operations when the parent directory doesn't exist.

```
byte[] myData = blah;//MyProgramm.Properties.Resources.Vorlage.csv

string myDocuments = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string myDataDir = myDocuments + "\\MyDataDir";

if(Directory.Exists(myDataDirectory)){
    Directory.Create(myDataDirectory);
}
// This needs to be outside the if block to ensure the data is written even
//   regardless of if the data directory previously existed or not
File.WriteAllBytes(myDataDirectory + "\\myFile.csv", myData);
```